# HTML to Markdown converter

Tags: javascript, converting, markdown

I've made a simple HTML→Markdown converter in Javascript and am looking for any feedback. For now, I've basically used Stack Exchange's `/editing-help` as a guide as to what to convert, but I might look at CommonMark's spec later on.

It uses `DOMParser()` and then goes through the child nodes to convert things.

My test HTML string right now is:

```
<h1>h1</h1> 
<br>
<h2>h2</h2> 
<br>
<h3>h3</h3> 
<br>text outside everything
<br>
<h2>(and another element!)</h2> 
<br>
<img src='http://example.com/example.png'>
<br><a href='http://google.com'>a link!</a> 
<br>
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
<br><strong>BOLD TEXT</strong> and <i>ITALICISED TEXT</i> 
<br>
<blockquote>blockquote</blockquote>
<br>
```

and that conversion 'works':

```
# h1 

## h2 

### h3 

text outside everything 

## (and another element!) 

![enter image description here](http://example.com/example.png) 

[a link!](http://google.com) 

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3


1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3


**BOLD TEXT** and *ITALICISED TEXT* 

> blockquote
```

### Code

```js
var str = "<h1>h1</h1> <br>"
str += "<h2>h2</h2> <br>";
str += "<h3>h3</h3> <br>";
str += "text outside everything <br>";
str += "<h2>(and another element!)</h2> <br>"
str += "<img src='http://example.com/example.png'> <br>";
str += "<a href='http://google.com'>a link!</a> <br>";
str += "<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul> <br>";
str += "<ol><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ol> <br>";
str += "<strong>BOLD TEXT</strong> and <i>ITALICISED TEXT</i> <br>";
str += "<blockquote>blockquote</blockquote>";

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
var childnodes = doc.body.childNodes;
var markdown = '';

var conversions = {
  br: function(data) {
    return '\n\n';
  },
  h1: function(data) {
    return '# '
  },
  h2: function(data) {
    return '## ';
  },
  h3: function(data) {
    return '### ';
  },
  hr: function(data) {
    return '---\n';
  },
  blockquote: function(data) {
    return '> ';
  },
  img: function(data) {
    var imgStr = "![alt text](" + data.curEl.src + ")";
    return imgStr;
  },
  a: function(data) {
    return "[" + data.html + "](" + data.curEl.getAttribute('href') + ")";
  },
  ul: function(data) {
    var lis = childnodes[data.i].childNodes;
    var newmd = '';
    var lislength = lis.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < lislength; x++) {
      newmd += "- " + lis[x].innerHTML + "\n";
    }
    return newmd;
  },
  ol: function(data) {
    var lis = childnodes[data.i].childNodes;
    var counter = 1;
    var newmd = '';
    var lislength = lis.length
    for (var x = 0; x < lislength; x++) {
      newmd += counter + ". " + lis[x].innerHTML + "\n";
      counter++;
    }
    return newmd;
  },
  strong: function(data) {
    return "**" + data.html + "**";
  },
  i: function(data) {
    return "*" + data.html + "*";
  }
};


function convertToMarkdown(curEl, html, tag, i) {
  if (tag == undefined) { //for text nodes
    markdown += curEl.textContent;
  } else {
    tag = tag.toLowerCase();
    console.log(tag);
    markdown += conversions[tag]({
      curEl: curEl,
      html: html,
      tag: tag,
      i: i
    }) + (['ul', 'ol', 'i', 'strong', 'a'].indexOf(tag) > -1 ? '' : html);
  }
}

var length = childnodes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var curEl = childnodes[i],
    html = childnodes[i].innerHTML,
    tag = childnodes[i].tagName;
  convertToMarkdown(curEl, html, tag, i);
}
console.log(markdown);
```

(you can check the output yourself in the console)

Main Questions:

- Is my code readable? How can I make it more so?
- Is there a cleaner way to do any part of this?

Comment: BTW I'm aware there are many converters that already exist - but I wanted to have a go myself...

Comment: Your code fails on `<ol>` starting at values other than 1. Also, `<ul>` tags have a space before the `-`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the counter is always starting at `1`, when the starting number can be, for example, 10.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel oh - so you mean I can't change the number? That's not a problem for me because I'm creating the HTML :)

Comment: Alright. That really isn't a problem then

Comment: @Ismael As far as I'm aware, you can't make numbered lists starting at anything but 1 in standard Markdown.

Comment: @Schism It actually works. Try writting an answer and start the list at 3. It will detect it and write the attribute `start`

Comment: @Ismael Yes, on SO's flavour. However, the standard doesn't currently permit it -- if you try it on Github, for instance, it won't work.

Comment: @Schism You are correct, but the flavour wasn't specified. So, I assumed it is the StackExchange flavour, since this site belongs to the network and has markdown too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't that much re-usable. I can't include it in a file and call it since I could easily break it from anywhere.

What I suggest is that you wrap it in the following block:

```
(function(window, undefined){
    'use strict';
    [code]
})(Function('return this')());
```

This will protect your code in so many ways:

- You guarantee that the `window` object is *the* `window`
- You guarantee that `undefined` is **really** `undefined`
- You can be 100% sure that there won't be variables on the global scope
- All variables are local (looks the same, but it is a tiny bit different)
- The possibility of a script screwing up your code is `null`.

And this takes what? 1 minute? And you have to change almost nothing!

---

You will notice the `'use strict;'` there. You may be alienated by it.

This has been re-re-re-re-re-re-itterated here. Using it adds some security features and prevent some 'stupid' bloopers and other mistakes and distractions.

You can read about it in greater detail on [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

---

You currently are writting everything into the `markdown` variable. Before going any further, let me take the liberty to teach you about the amazing `return` statement:

> When a `return` statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller. If the expression is omitted, `undefined` is returned instead.

<sub>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return</sub>

Inside your `convertToMarkdown()` function, instead of cramming it all into that variable, use a `return`.

---

Inside the same function, you have the following:

```
if (tag == undefined) { //for text nodes
    markdown += curEl.textContent;
} else {
```

Which **isn't** fine. It is too complex to explain in less than 20k characters, but that piece must be gone! I'll show how later on.

One of the problems with this is also that you are using `.textContent`. That isn't much compatible with other "browsers" (*`*cough*`* IE *`*cough*`*). The most compatible method is by using `.innerText`. But Firefox now decided that it wouldn't support it. Fear not, just add this line at the top:

```
var TEXT_PROPERTY = document.head.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
```

And use it like `curEl[TEXT_PROPERTY]` to get the text content.

---

Instead of re-creating a parser object, you can simply create a `<div>`, keep it in memory, and use it to extract the elements. Setting the `.innerHTML` of that element will have the same effect than the parser, but faster. You then have access to tons of tools readily available on DOM elements.

---

Your choice of newlines is quite weird. Browsers will all the time convert them to `\r\n`. You can use it, since you know what to expect. Imagine what would be to write `\n` and get `\r\n` instead. That would drive some guys insane!

---

On your `conversions` object, you have methods that have 1 argument, but use it for nothing. You could just drop that useless argument. Done.

---

And now, my promised alternative:

```
(function(window, undefined){
    'use strict';
    var TEXT_PROPERTY = document.head.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
    var NEWLINE = '\r\n';

    var indent = function(text){
        return text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'$1    ');
    };

    var conversions = {
        BR: function(){
            return '  ' + NEWLINE;
        },
        P: function(elem) {
            return NEWLINE + NEWLINE + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
        },
        H1: function(elem) {
            return '# ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
        },
        H2: function(elem) {
            return '## ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
        },
        H3: function(elem) {
            return '### ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
        },
        HR: function() {
            //we use 4 to do not cause confusion with <strike></strike>
            return '----' + NEWLINE;
        },
        BLOCKQUOTE: function(elem) {
            return '> ' + elem
                    .innerHTML
                    .replace(
                        /(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,
                        '$1> '
                    );
        },
        IMG: function(elem) {
            return '![alt text](' + elem.src + ')';
        },
        A: function(elem) {
            return '[' + elem.innerHTML + '](' + elem.href + ')';
        },
        UL: function(elem) {
            var li = elem.children;
            var length = li.length;
            var md = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                md += ' - ' + indent(li[i].innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
            }
            return md;
        },
        OL: function(elem) {
            var li = elem.children;
            var length = li.length;
            var md = '';
            var start = elem.start|0;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                md += (i + start) + '. ' + indent(li[i].innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
            }
            return md;
        },
        B: function(elem) {
            return '**' + elem.innerHTML + '**';
        },
        STRONG: function(elem) {
            return this.B(elem);
        },
        STRIKE: function(elem) {
            return '---' + elem.innerHTML + '---';
        },
        DEL: function(elem) {
            return this.STRIKE(elem);
        },
        I: function(elem) {
            return '*' + elem.innerHTML + '*';
        },
        PRE: function(elem){
            return indent(this.innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
        },
        CODE: function(elem){
            if(elem.parentNode.tagName != 'PRE')
            {
                return '``' + elem.innerHTML.replace(/\r|\n/g,'').replace(/^\s*(.*)\s*$/,'$1') + '``';
            }
            else
            {
                this.PRE(elem);
            }
        }
    };

    var toMarkdown = function(html){
        var DIV = document.createElement('div'); //will have the HTML to parse.

        DIV.innerHTML = html + '';

        for(var tag in conversions)
        {
            var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(DIV.getElementsByTagName(tag.toLowerCase()));
            var length = elements.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var element = elements[i];

                if(element.childNodes.length > 1)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = toMarkdown(element.innerHTML);
                }

                element.parentNode.replaceChild(
                    document.createTextNode(conversions[tag](element)),
                    element
                );
            }

        }

        return DIV.innerHTML;
    };

    window.MarkdownConverter = {
        addParser: function(tag, fn){
            if( !this.hasParser(tag) )
            {
                conversions[(tag + '').toUpperCase()] = fn;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        hasParser: function(tag){
            tag = (tag + '').toUpperCase();
            return (tag in conversions);
        },
        fromHTML: function(html){
            return toMarkdown(html + '');
        }
    };

})(Function('return this')());
```

It exposes a very basic API. The idea is to be as close as I can from the reference.
You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Some mistakes on matching the were fixed. Also, the original version was limited to 1 level only. Which means that things like `<p>A <b>bold</b></p>` wouldn't produce the right markdown. To fix that, I've added recursion. Also, the `<blockquote>` only had the markdown on the first line. All those issues and many others (that I don't remember) were fixed.

Another addition was the support for the `start` attribute (it was deprecated on HTML4.01, but it isn't on HTML5) on ordened lists.

Example of the markdown:

```js
(function(window, undefined){
 'use strict';
 var TEXT_PROPERTY = document.head.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
 var NEWLINE = '\r\n';
 
 var indent = function(text){
  return text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'$1    ');
 };
 
 var conversions = {
        BR: function(){
            return '  ' + NEWLINE;
        },
  P: function(elem) {
   return NEWLINE + NEWLINE + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
  },
  H1: function(elem) {
   return '# ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
  },
  H2: function(elem) {
   return '## ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
  },
  H3: function(elem) {
   return '### ' + elem.innerHTML + NEWLINE;
  },
  HR: function() {
   //we use 4 to do not cause confusion with <strike></strike>
   return '----' + NEWLINE;
  },
  BLOCKQUOTE: function(elem) {
   return '> ' + elem
                 .innerHTML
                 .replace(
                  /(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,
                  '$1> '
              );
  },
  IMG: function(elem) {
   return '![alt text](' + elem.src + ')';
  },
  A: function(elem) {
   return '[' + elem.innerHTML + '](' + elem.href + ')';
  },
  UL: function(elem) {
   var li = elem.children;
   var length = li.length;
   var md = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    md += ' - ' + indent(li[i].innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
   }
   return md;
  },
  OL: function(elem) {
   var li = elem.children;
   var length = li.length;
   var md = '';
            var start = elem.start|0;
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    md += (i + start) + '. ' + indent(li[i].innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
   }
   return md;
  },
  B: function(elem) {
   return '**' + elem.innerHTML + '**';
  },
  STRONG: function(elem) {
   return this.B(elem);
  },
  STRIKE: function(elem) {
   return '---' + elem.innerHTML + '---';
  },
  DEL: function(elem) {
   return this.STRIKE(elem);
  },
  I: function(elem) {
   return '*' + elem.innerHTML + '*';
  },
  PRE: function(elem){
   return indent(this.innerHTML) + NEWLINE;
  },
        CODE: function(elem){
            if(elem.parentNode.tagName != 'PRE')
            {
             return '``' + elem.innerHTML.replace(/\r|\n/g,'').replace(/^\s*(.*)\s*$/,'$1') + '``';
            }
            else
            {
                this.PRE(elem);
            }
        }
 };
 
 var toMarkdown = function(html){
  var DIV = document.createElement('div'); //will have the HTML to parse.
  
  DIV.innerHTML = html + '';
  
  for(var tag in conversions)
  {
   var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(DIV.getElementsByTagName(tag.toLowerCase()));
   var length = elements.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
    var element = elements[i];
   
    if(element.childNodes.length > 1)
    {
     element.innerHTML = toMarkdown(element.innerHTML);
    }
    
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(
     document.createTextNode(conversions[tag](element)),
     element
    );
   }
   
  }
  
  return DIV.innerHTML;
 };
 
 window.MarkdownConverter = {
  addParser: function(tag, fn){
   if( !this.hasParser(tag) )
   {
    conversions[(tag + '').toUpperCase()] = fn;
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  },
  hasParser: function(tag){
   tag = (tag + '').toUpperCase();
   return (tag in conversions);
  },
  fromHTML: function(html){
   return toMarkdown(html + '');
  }
 };
 
})(Function('return this')());


document.body.innerHTML=
    '<pre>' + 
     MarkdownConverter
      .fromHTML(
    document
     .getElementById('html')
     .innerHTML
   )
      .replace(/</g,'&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g,'&gt;') +
    '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="html">

  
<p>Te<i><b>s</b></i>t</p>
<h1>h1</h1> 
<br>
<h2>h2</h2> 
<br>
<h3>h3</h3> 
<br>text outside everything
<br>
<h2>(and another element!)</h2> 
<br>
<img src='http://example.com/example.png'>
<br><a href='http://google.com'>a link!</a> 
<br>
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ol start="2">
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item <b>3</b></li>
</ol>
<br><strong>BOLD TEXT</strong> and <i>ITALICISED TEXT</i> 
<br>
<blockquote>blockquote</blockquote>
<br>
  

</div>
```

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ If you want, make a new room and I can try to help on that.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I've added an alternative implementation. I hope you like it and suits your needs.

Comment: For the record, from ES5, `undefined` is read-only.

Comment: @Schism On the window object, it is. But you can create a local variable and set a value.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks! I'll look at it and see what/how it works over the next few days, but I've accepted it now! :) Sorry for  the delay; I've been away!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Don't worry. If you find something that doesn't make you that happy, just drop here a comment, or ping me on The 2nd Monitor.

Comment: @Ismael I have used a bit of your implementation for my final converter and it is now being used for my SE WYSIWYG editor at http://stackapps.com/q/6571/26088. :) thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ AWESOME! Thank you for picking my code! That is really awesome!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel welcome! :) And thanks for the upvote ;)

Answer (score 8):

A few things to point out:

---

> ```
>   ul: function(data) {
>     var lis = childnodes[data.i].childNodes;
>     var newmd = '';
>     var lislength = lis.length;
>     for (var x = 0; x < lislength; x++) {
>       newmd += "- " + lis[x].innerHTML + "\n";
>     }
>     return newmd;
>   },
> ```

You can declare `lislength` in the `for` loop, rather than externally, if you like.

```
for (var x = 0, listlength = list.length; x < listlength; x++) {
```

Also, note that you should keep your use of quotes consistent (`""` &  `''`)

This is especially helpful when trying to avoid re-calling a function, or a method call that is somewhat slow.

---

> ```
>   img: function(data) {
>     var imgStr = "![alt text](" + data.curEl.src + ")";
>     return imgStr;
>   },
> ```

You can just `return` `imgStr` without assigning it.

```
return "![alt text](" + data.curEl.src + ")";
```

---

> ```
>   strong: function(data) {
>     return "**" + data.html + "**";
>   },
> ```

`<strong>` is synonymous with `<b>`, so you may want to consider that, also.

---

On an abstraction note, you should be passing `var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');` to a class/function, at best, and leave the rest to be handled within the class/function, meaning `childnodes` and `markdown` would be better off buried within the structure, rather than as external globals.

Comment: Defining variables in the loop has no practical advantages, since all variables are function scope anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you need to extend your test regime a bit, as there are quite a few cases you don't cover. Here are some test cases you should consider:

- *Extraneous space within elements* – Have you tried stuff like `<strong> bolded text </strong>`. If this gets translated with the spaces, it will fail...
- *`<br>`'s within paragraph* – Poems, adresses, and some other stuff might use `<br>` within a paragraph, and as such should be translated into two spaces at the end of the line instead of the paragraph divider or `\n\n`
- *Nested lists* – Lists can, and are often nested. A proper translation should allow for this, and that means you need to keep track of current indentation level
- *Space in front of lists?* – Some markdown implementation also require that there is a newline in front of lists for them to be properly formatted. You should have a case or two testing this as well
- *Nested tags* – As someone else commented upon in their answer, what about nested tags? I.e. Bold and italics, lists with italics in list elements, blockquote with other tags, ...

What I'm trying to say here, is that you need to extend your test regime quite a bit, and get real life examples when testing. If possible, you should build more complex test scenarios in addition to the *happy flow* or *basic case* which you are already testing.